# Is it possible for a mapping to run out of space?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, storage, memory

Can storage mappings in a contract run out of space? Say that mapping was keyed to an `address` and the value as the following struct:

```
User
  bytes32 name
  uint8 age
```

Theoretically, if there was a `user` mapped to every possible address, would it ever run out of space? What if the struct had more variables?

Also, side question but on the same note. Do `dynamic arrays` have a max number of items? Can they only hold up to `uint8` worth of items?